# Best way to connect to Webdav on Sharepoint with NTLM Authentication Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, webdav

I am currently trying to connect to a private Sharepoint workspace (on our intranet) using Webdav that uses NTLM using davfs2. However I am failing due to this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/davfs2/+bug/1091183 (No NTLM support in davfs2).

Does anyone have any alternative suggestions for connecting - I would be as happy with a two-way syncing solution as with a FUSE solution.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue.

So I rebuilt the package from source. I struggled to find a way to rebuild davfs2 with libneon27 instead of libneon27-gnutls. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313741/rebuild-davfs2-with-libneon27-instead-of-libneon27-gnutls) is closed (I think incorrectly). So I had to figure it out (not very complicated anyway)

1. Install libneon with proper OpenSSL `sudo apt-get install libneon27 libneon27-dev`
2. Remove existing davfs2 if you already have it `sudo apt-get remove davfs2`
3. [Download davfs2 from source](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/davfs2/). I used version 1.5.2
4. Untar the file you just downloaded (something like `tar -xzvf davfs2-1.5.2.tar.gz` will work)
5. Change to the directory and launch `./configure`
6. Build with `make`
7. Install with `sudo make install`

Once you've built davfs with the proper binding, you can use davfs to mount a folder with something like (you may need to be root)

```
mount.davfs <url> <folder> -o ro
```

You'll be asked for credentials unless you configure your secret files. See more information at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man8/mount.davfs.8.html

Answer (score -1):

I do this in Ubuntu using the Storage Made Easy Free Linux client. It connect to my SharePoint fine using NTLM. You'll need a Storage Made Easy Account. Their Linux tools are at: http://storagemadeeasy.com/LinuxDrive/

It functions as a FUSE Drive and also offers separate Sync Tools.

Comment: Looks a nice service, but it won't do what I need as the SharePoint Server I need to access is inside a firewall