# Rebuild davfs2 with libneon27 instead of libneon27-gnutls

Tags: 13.04, compiling, bug-reporting, webdav

I can't connect to my office's sharepoint webdav with davfs2.

According to http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=668968, it's a bug with the libneon27-gnutls instead of libneon27.

How can I rebuild the davfs2 using libneon27 (as suggested by the first comment on the bug)?

Comment: I think this question is completely valid if you remove the version tag, since the issue still happens and it's needed to connect to Sharepoint from Linux. Admitely it can be pretty basic and maybe there are other similar questions in the site. Anyway, since this question is closed, I've replied more in detail in this other question http://askubuntu.com/a/707428/19175