# Using Webdav with Sharepoint Online

Tags: networking, mount, webdav

I realize that similar questions exist, for instance this: [Best way to connect to Webdav on Sharepoint with NTLM Authentication Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279810/best-way-to-connect-to-webdav-on-sharepoint-with-ntlm-authentication-ubuntu-12-1)

But across the board I keep coming back to the issue of: 
mount.davfs: Mounting failed.
403 FORBIDDEN

I want to send out feelers - has anyone ever successfully connected to Sharepoint Online on Ubuntu? Or is it just not possible?

I know for a fact that Total Command in Windows can connect to sharepoint online without using the Internet Explorer tokens. However Beesoft Commander has thus far only crashed on me for trying.